# Transmission-daemon keeps resetting

Tags: transmission

i have been trying to configure transmission-daemon so i can connect using the webui avaliable at http://server.ip-address:9091 , but i just get a message telling me that i should either disable the ip address whitelist or add my current ip to it.

I edited the file avaliable at /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json and modify the rpc-whitelist-enabled parameter to false, save the file and restart the service with: sudo service transmission-daemon restart. After that i double-check the settings.json i just modified just to discover that all my changes have been undone. What is goin on here?, any one else have seen this behaviour before?

Comment: Okay... just discovered what was going on, if you edit the settings.json file you must restart the service with: sudo invoke-rc.d transmission-daemon reload

Comment: Transmission daemon rewirtes the config file on exit. To edit it without overwrite you have to `sudo service transmission-daemon stop` before editing.

Comment: @con-f-use Please put your comment as an answer.  It deserves to be accepted as the correct response.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Transmission daemon re-writes the configuration file with the old options when it exits. To make your changes persist, you need to edit the configuration file without the deamon running. So first:

```
sudo stop transmission-daemon
```

Or if you did not install it via Software Center / Official repositories:

```
sudo killall -HUP transmission-da
```

Afterwards you can edit `settings.json` as you would expect and then restart transmission:

```
sudo start transmission-daemon
```

Comment: There's a GitHub issue asking to change this behavior. See here and upvote if it annoys you too. Although probably a PR would be more helpful: https://github.com/transmission/transmission/issues/882

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json` which seems to be file which is copied after every restart of the `systemd` unit `transmission-daemon.service`. I didn't find a reference, but a simple test confirms.

Comment: editing both didn't resolve my issue.  even when the service had been stopped.